# When creating an org-agenda-custom-commands command, how can I make the (agenda) portion only display certain tags?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-ql

I add custom `org-agenda` commands to the `org-agenda-custom-commands` like so

```
  (setq w-view
           `("W" "Work"
             (
              (agenda ""
                      (
                       (org-agenda-span 'day)
                       (org-deadline-warning-days 365)
                       ))
              (tags-todo "work"
                         ((org-agenda-overriding-header "All Work")
                          (org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/inbox.org"))
                          (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(deadline-up priority-down tag-up))
                          ))
              (tags-todo "work"
                         ((org-agenda-overriding-header "Work Projects")
                          (org-agenda-files '("~/Dropbox/org/projects.org"))
                          (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(deadline-up priority-down tag-up))
                          ))
              nil
              )
             )
           )
  (add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands `,w-view)
```

I understand that items can start with "agenda," "tags-todo," or "tags," and possibly other things, though I'm not clear on what exactly as the [documentation](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html) doesn't say.

I do know that an `agenda` item shows my `TODO` items that have deadlines or are scheduled, in order and with their timestamps. I also know that I can create custom headers, i.e. like I do for "All Work" or "Work Projects." I know that I can determine what `TODO` items are displayed under those custom headers because I start those sections with `tags-todo`.

What I don't understand is how I can make a custom section that starts with `agenda` only show `TODO` items of a certain tag.

I've tried the following:

```
          (agenda ""
                  ((tags-todo "work")
                   (org-agenda-span 'day)
                   (org-deadline-warning-days 365)
                   ))
```

Which didn't throw any errors but also shows all `TODO` items regardless of tags, i.e., didn't change anything.

**When making a custom org-agenda-custom-commands view, and using the "agenda" custom header identifier, how can I make that custom agenda view only display certain tags?**

I'm not sure what to call the "agenda" or "tags-todo" or "tags" custom header identifier, help in the vocabulary sense so I can edit and clarify this question would be appreciated.

Comment: Here is a link to the advanced searching section of the org-mode manual:  https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/advanced-searching.html  In addition to that, Sacha Chua has a nice section for the `org-agenda-custom-commands` you might like to take a look at:  https://pages.sachachua.com/.emacs.d/Sacha.html  When you get to Sacha's webpage linked in the previous sentence, just word-search for the term `org-agenda-custom-commands` and you can jump to her configuration and take a look

Comment: You can only use matching with `todo`, `tags` and `tags-todo`; you cannot use matching  with `agenda`. Do `C-h v org-agenda-custom-commands` to see its doc string. OTOH, the `org-agenda-tag-filter-preset` setting in the Sacha Chua document that @lawlist pointed you to might be just the ticket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done using built in tools using `org-agenda-skip-function` (I've used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10074016/org-mode-filter-on-tag-in-agenda-view) on Stack Overflow in the past).

If you don't mind external packages, [org-super-agenda](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-super-agenda) makes this easy:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("w" "Work agenda" agenda ""
              ((org-super-agenda-groups
                '((:discard (:not (:tag ("work"))))
                 ))
               )
        ))
```

This will remove any item that doesn't match the selector `(:tag ("work"))`, that is will show only `:work:` items.  This is also significantly faster than using `org-agenda-skip-function`.

You can give multiple tags and combine them using `:and` and `:or`.  For example,

```
(:or 
  (:not (:tag ("work"))) 
  (:and 
    (:tag ("home")) 
    (:tag ("urgent"))))
```

will match work items, but also `:urgent:` items at home.  For even more advanced matching, check out [org-ql](https://github.com/alphapapa/org-ql), which is very powerful and fast

Comment: By the way, I eventually did just make a custom `org-agenda-skip-function`, here's one that rejects anything not of todo type `PROJECT` : 

```  
(defun my/org-agenda-skip-entry-if-not-project ()
    "Skip entries that are not PROJECT type todos."
    (let ((todo (org-get-todo-state)))
      (if (and todo (string= todo "PROJECT"))
          nil
        (or (outline-next-heading) (goto-char (point-max))))))
```